# JS - How do I use getFilesAsync() to create an array of files inside a folder?

Tags: javascript

I read many documents about `getFilesAsync()`, but most of them give examples with just a list of file names in a folder. How do I use `getFilesAsync()` to create an array of files inside the folder?

Comment: use this `Windows.Storage.StorageFile.createStreamedFileAsync`.

Comment: Don't forgot this is Promise and I'm not guaranteed to work.

Comment: What's the difference between a "name list of files" and an "array of files"? Are you saying you want the array to contain the actual file contents of all files, or...?

Comment: can you possibly add some links to these getFilesAsync examples you speak of

Comment: nnnnn,yes exactly.

Comment: Jaromanda X,  https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/FolderEnumeration/js/js/scenario4.js
Here he has a name list of files. But I can't find the way I can use it as an array for my audio files.

Comment: In the sample you linked, `files` is an array of files. The sample uses it to show the names, but you can use it for whatever you like.